# foreach loop over TextBoxes in GroupBox iterates in reverse order?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I created four `TextBox`es (in this order: `textBox1`, `textBox2`,...) and put them one below the other inside a `GroupBox`. Then I added the Click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tb.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program and click the `Button` (when all the `TextBox`es are empty), this is the output I get:

> textBox4
>
> textBox3
>
> textBox2
>
> textBox1

Apparently the `foreach` loop iterated over the `GroupBox` controls in reverse order. I expected it to do it from `textBox1` to `textBox4` because this was the order they were created and put in the groupbox.

Why did the `foreach` loop in reverse? Just curious...

Comment: You are making assumptions about the underlying collection and the implementation of the `GetEnumerator` method. When you observe the data structure in Visual Studio (and expand the collection), what order do you see them in? Most collections do not guarantee order, if you need that then either use a sorted collection or sort prior to use.

Comment: TimSchmelter has confirmed the implementation, the assumption that the collection would enumerate in the order that items were added is obviously where the crux of the question lies. `foreach` is just compiler sugar around the state machine returned by `GetEnumerator`, which can have a completely custom implementation.

Comment: In what scenario is the order important?

Comment: @Jodrell I don't think it is important, the OP states it's just curiosity over why it "bucks the trend" of not iterating as added. Just goes to show you cannot trust implementations, trust contracts :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, I don't think the sequence of enumeration needs to be consistent between iterations, is that right? It just happens to remain in Z Order in this case because that is optimal for `Form`s implementation of screen rendering, I presume.

Comment: @Jodrell I'm not sure what the convention / rule is on iterating with regards to repeat iterations. This particular example is simply the implementation of the enumerator that returns them in Z-Order each time.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, sorry, I wasn't clear, I believe its bad practice to repeat the use of an enumerator (different question.) But two `IEnumerator`s returned by the same `GetEnuemrator` needn't yield results in the same order, even if the enumerable is unchanged. That is my assertion but, it is moot and another question I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controls are placed in order of the Z-order of the controls in the same parent container (top-most to bottom-most). How do you want to order them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (TextBox txt in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(g=>g.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()).ToList().Reverse<TextBox>())
        {
            //Write your logic here
        }
```